# How to Use HttpClient with Windows Proxy

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient

I set up a proxy through Windows settings (Internet Options) (proxy type is pac)

All Browsers work well with proxies (so proxy is active and working), but when I try to use httpclient, I get the following error

```
SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

this is my codes

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
                {
                    using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                    {
                        return await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    }
                }
            }
```

How can I use a proxy set on Windows in my app?

Comment: Which .NET version. According to the error message, may the target/proxy require TLS version higher than the default settings run by your application. Please take a look into `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol`

Comment: .net 5.0, i tested SecurityProtocol before and not worked

Comment: Instantiating a new HttpClient in a using block for every request is considered an antipattern. Better is to create one and use this.